# Erro ao salvar dados de um formulário em tabelas diferentes

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho duas tabelas Entries e Company que possuem relacionamento de 1 para 1

Tenho um formulario que o usuario seleciona se é pf ou pj, se for pj abre as opções para salvar a empresa.

Porém quando vou dar o $company->save() gera erro pois esta retornando em um array.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

segue o código!

https://gist.github.com/adgole/9679025

**Model Company**

```
<?php

class Company extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Company';
protected $softDelete = true;
protected $guarded = array('id');

public function Company() {

return $this->belongsTo('Entry', 'entries_id');

}

}
```

**Model Entry**

```
<?php

class Entry extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'entries';
protected $softDelete = true;
protected $guarded = array('id');

public static $rules = array(
'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
);

public function company() {

return $this->hasOne('Company', 'entries_id');

}
public function payments() {

return $this->hasMany('Payment', 'entries_id');

}



public function getStatusAttribute()
{
// Status do ultimo pagamento
$last_payment = $this->payments()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();

if ($last_payment) {
return $last_payment->status;
}
}

}
```

**EntryController**

```
public function store()
{
$entry = new \Entry(\Input::except(
'company_name',
'company_cnpj',
'company_cep',
'company_address',
'company_number',
'company_complement',
'company_neighborhood',
'company_city',
'company_state'
));


if ($entry->save()) {
$company = new \Company();
$company = \Input::only(
'company_name',
'company_cnpj',
'company_cep',
'company_address',
'company_number',
'company_complement',
'company_neighborhood',
'company_city',
'company_state'
);
dd($company);
$company->entries_id = $entry->id;

$company->save();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Na linha 74 vc pega os dados de input em array. Por isso não da certo. Na linha 73 vc cria um objeto e na debaixo vc atribui um array.

Coloque o array em outra variável e da um `$company->fill($input)` por exemplo.